# Python: numpy.loadtxt dtype

Tags: python, numpy

Hey I want to save some data to variable which can store 4 float type data.
I want to save data to A variable. I have a text file with looks like this:

```
-130    8.54    4.944   0.85    3.996   11.445  10.765  0.85    0.68    8.516   4.561   0.85    3.999
```

I want to keep from 1st to 4th column in A variable. And I don't get how to specify dtype to do this?
That what i did but it of course doesn't work:

```
A = numpy.loadtxt("tabela.txt", dtype=[('A_col', 'f8'), ('B_col', 'f8'), ('C_col', 'f8'), ('D_col', 'f8')], usecols=(1, 4))
```

I saw every example for data type but no one seems to be clear for me in my case.
I want to keep these informations in A variable for example like that:
print(A[0]['A_col']) etc.

EDIT: with this code im getting this error: "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: You've made it very complicated.  Isn't `np.loadtxt('tablea.txt')[:4]` exactly what you want?

Comment: Or if there are multiple lines, `np.loadtxt('tablea.txt')[:,:4]`?

Comment: @TimRoberts I want save whole column in A[A_col], next col in A[B_col] etc.

Comment: Since text values are all numbers it may be simplest to load the whole thing, and use normal array slicing or reshaping after.  Don't try to do something fancy with loadtxt if you don't have to.

Comment: Ok, but anyway nice to know how to specify dtype. After all, this is one of the features of loadtxt

Comment: Anyway, @TimRoberts this slice notation works fine and I figured out how to use it in my example (first time i use it) but it doesn't answer to question about dtype. Im just interesting how it works

Comment: if you specify 4 fields in the dtype, you need 4 values in usecols.  We like to see the full traceback with errors.